# MouseEvents not firing as expected using MVVM approach

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to capture mouse events on a control using an MVVM approach. I'm using blend event triggers to invoke commands.

In this example below, I have a uniform grid and each item in the grid is rendered as a rectangle. I want to record simple gestures (like when a user draws a line) so I'd like to execute a command when the mouse button goes down, moves over a few items and then is lifted.

I'm placing the event triggers on the rectangle because i want to capture which viewmodel item was used to start or end the so-called gesture.

Seems that *PreviewMouseDown* and *PreviewMouseUp* are not fired as part of the Rectangle. However, if I move these events to the *UniformGrid* they fire correctly, but I don't have the item that was used to start/end the gesture.

The *MouseEnter* command fires as expected.

Any thoughts as to why the Preview* events are not firing, or can you suggest different markup?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Rows}" Columns="{Binding Columns}" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Rectangle Fill="Red">
             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                         Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                         />
                 </i:EventTrigger>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                         Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.StartGesture, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                         />
                 </i:EventTrigger>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                         Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EndGesture, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                         />
                 </i:EventTrigger>
             </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I should invest in a [rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html). In taking the time to ask the question, I copy pasted the code into the editor and then cleaned it up. In doing so, I actually wrote the correct markup.

A few hours later, after dinner and some time to clear my head. I was dismayed to see that no one had answered my question. I went back to my IDE and the binding errors in the Output window were impossible to miss! The StartGesture/EndGesture commands were missing the RelativeSource part of the command binding and were failing.

Carry on, stackoverflow. Nothing to see here.